# Rails: Default route not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I have added default route in my `routes.rb` file like below:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

But its not working. What need to be done for a catch all requests in **Rails 5.0**

Comment: `match` in Rails5?..

Comment: Hope you deleted the default index file generated...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is exactly your question :

It's not really recommended to do this, but you'll find more information in [rails guidelines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments).

To have routes matching all requests (working in rails 4, not sure in rails 5):

```
match ':controller(/:action)(.:format)', via: [:get, :put, :post, :patch]
match ':controller(/:id(/:action))(.:format)', via: [:get, :put, :post, :patch]
```

The default route of application should be defined like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For using 'match' in rails5, check here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean because the question is ambiguous. Hopefully this solves your problem

To have matching routes for all requests in Rails 5

```
match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: [:get, :post]
match 'photos', to: 'photos#show', via: :all
```

where `photos` = `route`, `photos#show` = `controller#action`
the `via` method takes an array containing `HTTP verbs` or `:all` which will link to all `HTTP verbs`

Check out [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints)

Default routes can be set using

```
root 'controller#action'
```

Or you can define all the routes for a controller using

```
resources :controller_name
```